# Appending a list to a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe let's say:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    x    3
1    y    4
```

and I have a list:

```
2
3
4
5
```

Can I append the list to the data frame like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    x    3
1    y    4
2    Nan  Nan
3    Nan  Nan
4    Nan  Nan
5    Nan  Nan
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,5], columns=['col1']))
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,5], columns=['col1'])])


print (df)
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    x   3.0
1     1    y   4.0
0     2  NaN   NaN
1     3  NaN   NaN
2     4  NaN   NaN
3     5  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Tried this approach and I ended up getting the error - "ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned"

Comment: @Dhanendra Obviously problem is duplicated columns names.

Comment: I was so concentrated on the append and contact operation that I forgot to check the main df column name my bad! BTW thanks @jezrael